# Filtering the list items python

Tags: python

i need to select the list contents with (gr,bl,wh) two lettres. by excluding the words greater than two letters.i have a list that is in the given format..Any suggestion will help.

```
[red, gr, yellow]
[blue, wh, rose]
[orange, res, pink]
[red, bls, black]
[orange, re, pink]
[orange, re, pink]
```

the out put should look like

```
[red,  gr, yellow]
[blue, wh, rose]
[orange, re, pink]
[orange, re, pink]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a conditional list comprehension to filter the sublists where the length of second item is not equal to two.

```
my_lists = [
    ['red', 'gr', 'yellow'],
    ['blue', 'wh', 'rose'],
    ['orange', 'res', 'pink'],
    ['red', 'bls', 'black'],
    ['orange', 're', 'pink'],
    ['orange', 're', 'pink'],
]

>>> [sublist for sublist in my_lists if len(sublist[1]) == 2]
[['red', 'gr', 'yellow'],
 ['blue', 'wh', 'rose'],
 ['orange', 're', 'pink'],
 ['orange', 're', 'pink']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to filter `l`:

```
>>> l = [['red','blue','green'],['red', 're', 'blue']]
>>> [x for x in l if any(len(w) == 2 for w in x)]
[['red', 're', 'blue']]
```

Which filters sublists that have `any()` word with a length of 2

Comment: why `not all( > 2)` and not simply `any(== 2)`?